# PlayOnLinux Unable to find 32bit opengl libraries Dual ATI Videocards

Tags: 12.04, drivers, ati, 64-bit, playonlinux

Im curently running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64Bit

So, i installed league of legends fine the first time with the opensource ATI Drivers provided by ubuntu itself with no issues at all, but it runs so slow ... max 20fps because those drivers dont fully support my Dual Graphic cards

Than i restored system and i installed the Linux Version of the Proper ATI Drivers from the AMD Website wich supports my APU AMD-A8-4500M with the AMD Radeon 7640G + 7670M Graphics Cards enabling me full performance from my system .. Problem is, to run League of Legends i need a 32bit opengl library, and the driver, automaticly detects a 64bits Linux install and loads the 64bit libraries but not the 32 ones .

i need some kind of command, to force the 32bit libraries to load, or to make League of Legends run on the 64 ones ..

Im kinda noob to ubuntu ..
i installed the 32 bits ones trough terminal and still doesnt work idk why, maybe the driver doesnt want to load them .. plzz help me on this, i dont want to go back to windows just to play league

since im noob idk what more details to post here so plz tell me what do you need

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to suggest possible solutions that are merely trial and error. I am no expert in the matter, so take caution when implementing any of my suggestions.

First, I would like to suggest doing the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

This should pull in some 32-bit libraries; perhaps the one you need? If this works, hooray! Don't touch anything else.

If that didn't work, completely remove the AMD proprietary drivers. I have no idea how you installed them, but this link is fairly sufficient: http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Precise_Installation_Guide#Removing_Catalyst.2Ffglrx

```
sudo sh /usr/share/ati/fglrx-uninstall.sh
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx fglrx_* fglrx-amdcccle* fglrx-dev*
sudo apt-get remove --purge xserver-xorg-video-ati xserver-xorg-video-radeon
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-ati
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri xserver-xorg-core
sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.backup
sudo rm -rf /etc/ati
```

If the fifth command doesn't work, replace with:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 xserver-xorg-core
```

Then reinstall your proprietary driver. In 12.04, open the dash and open the "Additional Drivers" application (or alternatively, run "jockey-gtk" from the command line). Install the latest driver from that program (fglrx-updates). You will NOT get the latest and greatest driver, but you WILL get a driver that has been tested by Canonical and just works. You could get newer drivers (the link I've provided is able to show you one such method. You could also use an x-swat or xorg-edgers PPA, but they're beyond the scope of this question).

One tip, though: Don't mess with graphics drivers. A clean install has the best possible set-up for graphics in most of the cases. Drivers downloaded from websites are always shaky unless you know what you're doing. Drivers from PPAs are generally unstable. The only drivers you should really be using are the drivers Ubuntu ships with (i.e., the open source ones) or the ones downloadable through the "Additional Drivers" program.

I do not know whether the fault of PlayOnLinux lies in a bad driver set-up, but I personally think that's the culprit.

One last thing, since you're using an AMD APU:

```
sudo apt-get install amd64-microcode
```

This nifty little package solves a lot of problems with AMD APUs.

Comment: Thing is, the first sudo code, you gave me, i have that installed already and still no fix ..  As for removing the drivers and installing the new ones .. i had that already, but it was very slow in League of Legends, Max 20 fps because it was not using all my potential, as for the driver i downloaded itself was from here    
http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx

Right now i reinstalled ubuntu, from 12.04 to a fresh release of 13.04 ... i installed the latest beta driver from that ling trough
cd Desktop   and than  sudo sh (driver name)

Comment: Than i installed wine, and play on linux ... it didnt gave me the error and i tought, hm maybe its working .. but than i updated playonlinux to the latest version and started giving me that error again .. i wonder why ? sometimes i think ubuntu just doesnt want me to play League of Legends no more :(   as for the drivers i really dont want to use the provided by ubuntu as in they have a very low performance, while the official amd drivers for linux have full performance .. i really dont know what to do

Comment: Well if you want to live on the bleeding edge, remove all drivers following my instructions, and do this: "sudo apt-add-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa" followed by "sudo apt-get update". Then open synaptic ("sudo apt-get install synaptic"), look for "fglrx" in the search box and install the latest version.