# PlayOnLinux missing openGL 32 libraries

Tags: radeon, playonlinux, opengl

so I'm using Kubuntu 64 bit. (well that's ubuntu forum, but this is ubuntu derivative so I thought you might help me) and I wanted to install League of Legends through playonlinux (4.2.4). On 32 bit systems (Kubuntu and Ubuntu) process went flawlessly, but here playonlinux gives me error:

[image: POL error]

I am using radeon r7 (R7 265 2GB OC) drivers installed through drivers section

[image: radeon drivers installed]

fglrx - 13.35.5 [Mar. 12 2014]

So far I have tried these solutions given in forums:

sudo apt-get install ia32-libs [from here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/334629/playonlinux-unable-to-find-32bit-opengl-libraries-dual-ati-videocards)

and tried this [post here](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/topic-9507.html), but didn't install give libraries at all.

Since this is my first time playing with Linux 64 bit. I have no idea what am I doing! If someone could help I would appreciate that!

---

HEY!! I have solved this by entering

> dpkg --add-architecture i386

then removed old ATI drivers:

> sudo apt-get purge fglrx*

remove xorg.conf:

> sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf

reinstall xorg:

> sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-core libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64

reconfigure xorg:

> sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg

REBOOT

download latest amd drivers from [website](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download)

and install using this simple [youtube guide](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=evqpassbyqA)

that's it!! PlayOnLinux error is gone!! works perfectly fine! this worked on AMD Radeon R7 265 OC

Comment: sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install build-essential close & re open playonlinux

Comment: closed PoL, installed-build essentials, re opened the app but the same error remained

Comment: i think the libgl is missing so we can only try & find the missing package, install the libgl & try again
apt-get install fglrx

Comment: how to install libgl? I can't do that directly through terminal and entering that in synaptic gives me tons of packages, some of those are installed though should I give a list of installed packages?